# Junit test run freezes

Tags: java, testing, junit, automation

Today was my first contact with Junit so i had a little practice with some programs that return ints and it worked ok. Then i wanted to try to return a boolean and when i run the test case , it doesn't do anything, it's running but the bar doesn't turn green or red.

this is the class:

```
public class primcheck {

    public boolean prim(int n) {
        int nr=0;
        int i;
        while(nr==0) {
            for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++) {
                if(n%i==0) nr++;
            }

        }
        if(nr==0) return true;
         return false;


    }       
}
```

and the Junit test case

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class primeTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        primcheck pc = new primcheck();
        boolean output = pc.prim(5);
        assertEquals(false,output);
    }

}
```

Can you please explain to me what i did wrong? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Since you're mentioning a bar turning green or red, could you explain what environment you are running in?

Comment: Latest version of eclipse,  https://gyazo.com/f1e42adc0d7c7ea5cddcff72631f1a23 the bar is in the top left

Comment: Are you sure your loop ever exits?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nothing to do with JUnit. You'd have the same problem if you ran it "by hand".

```
    int nr=0;
    int i;
    while(nr==0) {
        for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++) {
            if(n%i==0) nr++;
        }

    }
```

If you never find a factor with the innermost `if`, you will just keep on looping indefinitely, because nothing makes `nr==0` false: after executing the `for` loop once, you just keep on running the while loop without executing the for loop body.

Remove the `while` loop, and add the condition to the for loop guard (or just omit it entirely):

```
        for(i=2;i<=n/2 && nr==0;i++) {
```

Comment: @AnghelAlexandru then you've got some problem with the test setup, because [it runs fine "by hand"](https://ideone.com/53iObQ).

Comment: but i don't understand, i've tried other test cases where it returned an int and it worked ...it's strange

Comment: @AnghelAlexandru because of `while (nr == 0)` your method could go into infinite loop if inside `for` loop `nr` was not incremented. This is what happened in your test. Basically your test did its work very well: it found an issue in your code